# Uncaught TypeError: check.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

It shows the problem "Uncaught TypeError: check.addEventListener is not a function". what i m trying to do tha when i click one of those video the class will be add and video width will be increase if i click another video the class will be remove automactically from 1st clicked video and add class on recent clicked video. plz any body help also check the if there is any css property problem and silve the ans through my problem

### Here is my Html File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test video</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        video{
            width: 300px;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .vid{
            width: 500px;
            transition: .5s;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video class="videoElementID" controls
    poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="C:\Users\Narayan Maity\Desktop\huhuuu\pehle pehle kabhi toh gam tha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script
      src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous">      
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### here is my test.js or javascript file

```
var check = document.querySelectorAll("video");   

check.addEventListener("click",cheesy());

function cheesy() {

    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        check[i].classList.remove("vid");
    }
    check.className += 'vid';
};
```

Comment: querySelectorAll() returns an array. So you need to iterate over the array to add those event listeners.

* actually a nodelist. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

You should loop each video element and add the click event listener

```
var check = document.querySelectorAll("video");   
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    check[i].addEventListener("click",cheesy);
}

function cheesy() {

    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        check[i].classList.remove("vid");
    }
    check.className += 'vid';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (an array of Nodes). Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Probably you want to add the event listener to each node.

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll("video"); 

Array.prototype.forEach.call(checks, function(item) {
   item.addEventListener("click",cheesy);
});
```

Comment: What's the benefit of accessing forEach from Array's prototype object as opposed to accessing the inherited forEach method from NodeListPrototype ? Not being malicious, just wondering?

Comment: @senojoeht not all browsers implement forEach in NodeList. I remember that IE 10 doesn't. This can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach so the developer can either use a polyfill or the Array's prototype forEach.

Comment: I know that nowadays if the project/developer is supporting only the newest browsers, there is no need to do this. But because of retrocompatibility I'm used to write this way for years...

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are passing a value as a result of executing the function `chessy()`. What you need to do is to pass the reference to your handler function as displayed below.

```js
check.addEventListener("click",cheesy);
```